# Changing location of 3D object in Unity

Tags: 3d

I need a simple script to change XYZ location of  3d object (.obj) on Unity3D.  I click on a button and object must change his location to a new certain location. I don't know C#. Can you help me please?
Sorry for my English

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty game object and drag this script onto it.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class LocationController : MonoBehaviour 
{
    // Drag the object you want to move into this field
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _objectToChangeLocation;

    // Enter your desired new location
    [SerializeField] private Vector3 _newLocation;

    // For your button component, drag the game object holding this script
    // and select this method
    public void ChangeLocation()
    {
        _objectToChangeLocation.transform.position = _newLocation;
    }
}
```